# How to preserve scaled circular shapes when combining graphics?

Tags: graphics, scaling, faq

The following code

```
g1 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.01], Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 10}}], Disk[{5, 3}, Scaled[0.1]]}, Frame -> True]
```

produces the following output

[image]

I then create another graphic with a non-square aspect ratio, and then combine the two graphics together:

```
g2 = Graphics[{Blue, Thickness[0.01], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {20, 10}}]}];
Show[g1, g2]
```

In this case, I obtain the following output with a squashed disk:

[image]

This can, of course, be fixed by specifying an aspect ratio of 1:

```
Show[g1, g2, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

But this gives rise to various other problems when combining multiple graphics and then forcing the combined graphic to have an aspect ratio of 1 (in particular when the coordinate height and width of the combined graphics are very different).

So, I'm wondering if there is a way to preserve scaled circular shapes when combing graphics without needing to adjust the aspect ratio. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of `Disk` you can use `Offset` radius specification, but it will make the radius independent from the scale of the plot:

```
g1 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.01], Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 10}}], 
    Disk[{5, 3}, Offset[20]]}, Frame -> True];
g2 = Graphics[{Blue, Thickness[0.01], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {20, 10}}]}];
Show[g1, g2]
```

> [image: output]

`Inset` offers more flexibility:

```
g1 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.01], Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 10}}], 
    Inset[Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}], {5, 3}, {0, 0}, 2.5]}, 
   Frame -> True];
g2 = Graphics[{Blue, Thickness[0.01], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {20, 10}}]}];
Show[g1, g2]
```

> [image: output]

(Note that you can specify the size of `Inset` also in `Scaled` and `Offset` forms.)

When you need *exactly* **filled** disks, you can use `Point` instead of `Disk` to get what you want (this also is beneficial from the performance viewpoint):

```
g1 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.01], Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 10}}], 
    PointSize[0.1], Point[{5, 3}]}, Frame -> True];
g2 = Graphics[{Blue, Thickness[0.01], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {20, 10}}]}];
Show[g1, g2]
```

> [image: output]

Comment: Thanks for the response. What would you suggest doing if one of the various graphics to be combined included many disks (say, hundreds)? Would a single inset work for all of them, or would I need to have a different inset for each of them?

Comment: @AnInquiringMind I would suggest to use `Translate` with `Inset` as the argument (if all disks should be the same). If the disks should be different, then probably you need separate `Inset` for each of them. But you could also try to experiment with a single `Inset` containing a lot of disks if the performance is critical for you.

Comment: @AnInquiringMind I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I had actually shifted away from using `Point` a while ago, in part because of the greater flexibility allowed by `Disk`, but this might get me to move back. Will explore further.