# How to scale a vertical quantity (e.g., scaled offset) with the width of a plot?

Tags: graphics, visualization, scaling

As stated in the Mathematica documentation,

> `PointSize[d]` is a graphics directive which specifies that points which follow are to be shown if possible as circular regions with diameter `d`. **The diameter `d` is given as a fraction of the total width of the plot.**

On the other hand,

> `Scaled[{dx,dy,...},{x_0,y_0,...}]`
>   gives a position obtained by starting at ordinary coordinates `x_0,y_0,...`, then moving by a scaled offset `{dx,dy,...}`.

In this case, the scaled offsets are specified as a fraction of **each plot direction**.

This leads to an apparent incompatibility in combining circular objects whose sizes are determined by the width of the plot (and because they are circular, their extent along the vertical direction is also specified by the width of the plot) and objects with vertical offsets which are determined by the height of the plot -- **how can this be reconciled?**

As an example, if I apply a horizontal offset, the offset objects are positioned as expected (on the boundary of the points), regardless of the specified plot range:

```
sites = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 1}], 1];
psize = 0.12;
offset = psize/2;

Graphics[{PointSize[psize], Map[Point[#] &, sites], PointSize[0.2 psize], 
          Red, Map[Point[Scaled[{offset, 0}, #]] &, sites]}, 
          PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> True]
Graphics[{PointSize[psize], Map[Point[#] &, sites], PointSize[0.2 psize], 
          Red, Map[Point[Scaled[{offset, 0}, #]] &, sites]},
          PlotRange -> {{-1, 4}, Automatic}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]
[image]

If I try the same with a vertical offset, however, the offsets do not remain fixed since the point size is changing as the width of the plot is adjusted:

```
Graphics[{PointSize[psize], Map[Point[#] &, sites], PointSize[0.2 psize], 
          Red, Map[Point[Scaled[{0, offset}, #]] &, sites]}, 
          PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> True]
Graphics[{PointSize[psize], Map[Point[#] &, sites], PointSize[0.2 psize], 
          Red, Map[Point[Scaled[{0, offset}, #]] &, sites]},
          PlotRange -> {{-1, 4}, Automatic}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]
[image]

Is there way to specify a vertical offset based on the width of the plot, or some other way to resolve this issue?

Lastly, I am using `Point` rather than `Disk` because of flattening that occurs do to scaling, as discussed [in this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176091/how-to-preserve-scaled-circular-shapes-when-combining-graphics). So any solution that needs to replace `Point` with `Disk` would preferably have a way of resolving the flattening issue, as well.

Thank you!

Comment: You could use `AspectRatio ->1` but that would distort the axis scales, which is probably not something you want...

Comment: @Jens Yeah, that wouldn't be an ideal solution, as it does cause various problematic distortions. Thanks for the response, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know in advance that the option value for `AspectRatio` is, say,  `ar`   you can simply use `offset / ar` for the vertical offset. If not, you can post-process the `Graphics` output to extract the `AspectRatio` and make the necessary change in `Scaled` coordinates using `ReplaceAll`:

```
ClearAll[aRatio, adjustScaled]
aRatio =  AspectRatio /. AbsoluteOptions[#, AspectRatio] &;
adjustScaled = # /. Scaled[a_, b___] :> Scaled[{1, 1 / aRatio[#]} a, b] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
sites = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 1}], 1];
psize = 0.12;
offset = psize/2;

g3 = Graphics[{PointSize[psize], Map[Point[#] &, sites], 
    PointSize[0.2 psize], Red, Map[Point[Scaled[{0, offset}, #]] &, sites]}, 
   PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> True];
g4 = Graphics[{PointSize[psize], Map[Point[#] &, sites], 
    PointSize[0.2 psize], Red, Map[Point[Scaled[{0, offset}, #]] &, sites]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 4}, Automatic}, Frame -> True];
g5 = Show[g3, AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {-1, 2}}];

Row[{g3, adjustScaled @ g3}, Spacer[10]] // Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}] &
```

[image]

```
Row[{g4, adjustScaled @ g3}, Spacer[10]] // Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}] &
```

[image]

```
Row[{g5, adjustScaled @ g3}, Spacer[10]] // Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}] &
```

[image]

The point sizes scale with the image size:

```
ag4 = adjustScaled @ g4;
frames = Table[Pane[Show[ag4, ImageSize -> s], 
   ImageSize -> {500, 300}, Alignment -> Center], 
  {s, Join @@ {#, Reverse @ Most @ #} & @ Range[100, 500, 10]}];
Export["g4.gif", frames]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I will have to test this out in non-contrived situations to get a sense of the performance hit, but it does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use [`PointSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PointSize) and [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled), why not use [`AbsolutePointSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsolutePointSize) and [`Offset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Offset)? For example (note that I tweaked your code slightly to use [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples) to generate the sites and a single [`Point`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Point) object where possible):

```
sites = Tuples[{Range[0,3], Range[0,1]}];
psize = 40;
offset = psize/2;

Graphics[
    {
    AbsolutePointSize[psize], Point[sites],
    AbsolutePointSize[.2 psize], Red, Point[Thread[Offset[{offset,0}, sites], List, -1]]
    },
    PlotRange->Automatic,
    Frame->True
]

Graphics[
    {
    AbsolutePointSize[psize], Point[sites],
    AbsolutePointSize[.2 psize], Red, Point[Thread[Offset[{0, offset}, sites], List, -1]]
    },
    PlotRange->Automatic,
    Frame->True
]
```

[image]

[image]