# Plot markers getting compressed in double y -axis plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, marker

I have to plot a list plot with the double y-axis; range `y1 = {0, 125}` and range `y2 = {100, 900}`. I have to use markers for the points in the plot. I have used the following code to create markers for the plots

```
markers1={Graphics[Disk[],ImageSize->8],Graphics[Rectangle[],ImageSize->8],Graphics[Simplex[{{0,0},{1,1},{2,0}}],ImageSize->12]};
markers2={Graphics[Disk[],ImageSize->20],Graphics[Rectangle[],ImageSize->20],Graphics[Simplex[{{0,0},{1,2},{2,0}}],ImageSize->22]};
```

I have used `ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"]` to combine the plots.

But the markers in the second y-axis plot is getting compressed. The picture is attached.
How can make all the markers same?
[image]

Comment: Please post all your code and data. It is hard to answer this given just the plot markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [`Offset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Offset.html)-type coordinates for your plot markers (see also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176091/how-to-preserve-scaled-circular-shapes-when-combining-graphics)):

```
markers = {
   Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, Offset@5], ImageSize -> 20], Graphics[Rectangle[Offset[{-5, -5}], Offset[{5, 5}]], ImageSize -> 20], Graphics[Simplex[Offset /@ {{-5, -5}, {0, 5}, {5, -5}}], ImageSize -> 22]
   };

SeedRandom[2];
ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][
 ListLinePlot[RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {3, 5}], PlotMarkers -> markers, Frame -> True],
 ListLinePlot[RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {3, 5}], PlotMarkers -> markers, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Dashed],
 "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"
 ]
```

[image]

(Note also that I have made sure the markers are centered around `{0,0}` to make sure they are properly aligned, see [`AlignmentPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AlignmentPoint.html) for more details)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the above problem.
You can change the shape of the circle and rectangle in the marker2 to fit the compression. Here is the code.

```
     markers2={Graphics[Disk[{0,0},{1.5,10}],ImageSize->8],Graphics[Rectangle[{0,0},{1,5}],ImageSize->8],Graphics[Simplex[{{0,0},{1,10},{2,0}}],ImageSize->12]};
```